# handling on no argument in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, jquery-1.7

I have little experience in javascript but in other programming languages the following is possible, to set a default value for a missing parameter in a function.

For instance lets say i have a function

```
function foo(a , b)
  return a + b 
{
```

I would like to be able to call the above function with 1 parameter or with 2 parameters

**one parameter case:**

```
foo(2)   //a =2 and b would be automatically set to a default no argument value,
```

**two parameter case:**

```
foo(1,2)  // a = 1 , b = 2 => 3
```

Is this possible in javascript that is IE 8 compatible or using Jquery 1.7.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript functions allow you to call them with less parameters than specified.

What you're trying to accomplish is  possible doing something like the following:

```
function foo(a , b){
  if(typeof b === "undefined"){
      b=3;
  }
  return a + b; 
}
foo(5);//return 3;
```

I strongly suggest that you check for `undefined` and *not* rely on the `||` operator. I've spent hours debugging code that made that assumption and failed when passing `0` or another falsy value. The JavaScript type system can get really tricky, for example `"0"` is falsy.

ECMAScript Harmony (the next version) allows default parameters like in those other languages using the following syntax

```
function foo(a , b=3){
  return a + b;
}
```

This does not work in IE8 like the first version though.

Comment: This is the best answer, you're the only one who's actually checking for `undefined`...

Comment: yeah the undefined check is really needed

Comment: @pyCthon If you like my answer please consider accepting it, or telling me what parts you did not think are clear enough so I can improve it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum its perfectly clear I just couldn't accept this as an answer with in certain time limit in which i went afk until now

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. If a parameter isn't passed, you get a special value "undefined". The following works for me:

```
function foo(a, b) {
  a = a || defaultForA;
  b = b || defaultForB;

}
```

Due to the way Javascript treats conversion to boolean, the following will all be considered undefined in the above code snippet:

```
undefined
null
0
"" (empty string)
false
```

So if those values are important to you, you'll need to explicitly test for undefined rather than the blanket "if not false" test being used above.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can simulate this effect manually with a tertiary operator or an if statement (just make sure you check for `undefined`!):

```
function foo(a, b) {
    b = (typeof b === "undefined") ? 2 : b;

    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An undefined parameter evaluates as false, so you can do something like this in the beggining of your function foo:

```
a = a || 0;
b = b || 0;
```

That way if a or b exist, they will be evaluated with their own values and with 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can just test if you received a parameter:

```
function foo(a, b) {
  if(typeof b === "undefined") {b = 2;}
}
```

By testing for "undefined" you can also accept parameters that evaluate to false (like `null` or `""` or `0` or `false`)